# Multi-user option not avilable in Android one after Lollipop update

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, multi-user, android-one

I have Karbonn Android one phone. It is updated to Lollipop 5.1. I read that multi-user option is available in Lollipop. But in Settings the Users option is not available.

How can I enable it? Is it not supported by Android one phones?

Answer (score 5):

It is supported, but you must have **rooted** device.

Download file manager that allows root access(for example: **ES File Explorer**)

Navigate to `/system/`

**Backup** `build.prop`

Add these lines at the end of build.prop file:

`fw.show_multiuserui=1`

`fw.max_users=5`

Save and reboot device

If something went wrong, restore `build.prop` backuped version from recovery.

Comment: Thanks, it worked excellent on my Moto G 2nd gen XT1079, stock Lollipop 5.0.2!

Answer (score 5):

You can enable multiuser support without rooting the device by using ADB.

1. Enable debug mode (developer settings)
2. Connect the device via USB to a PC with ADB installed.
3. Execute these commands:

   ```
   adb shell setprop fw.show_multiuserui 1  
   adb shell setprop fw.max_users 4
   ```

The settings might be lost after reboot. I'm sure it's possible to modify the `build.prop` file from ADB too, but I'm not that experienced yet.

Comment: @Bert, yes it is possible to modify build.prop file from adb, but you need root access to do this :)

Answer (score 3):

It can be enabled without rooting.

You must have JDK (including platform tools) and proper ADB drivers installed.

1. First, download TWRP Recovery for Android one (sprout) and paste it in
   `c\program files\andrdk\platform-tools`. Rename it to "twrp".
2. Connect your device.
3. Right click on `platform-tools` folder holding left-shift and click on 
   "Open command window from here".
4. Type `adb reboot bootloader` -- this will boot phone into fastboot mode.

   Then type `fastboot boot twrp.img` -- this will boot the device into 
   TWRP recovery temporarily.
5. In recovery click `mount`, then check `system`.
6. Type `adb pull /system/build.prop` -- this will copy the `build.prop` into the `platform-tools` folder.
7. Open the `build.prop` file using notepad++ (simple notepad may corrupt the file), add the following two lines at the bottom and then save it:

   ```
   fw.show_multiuserui=1
   fw.max_users=3
   ```
8. Type `adb push build.prop /system/` -- this will push the edited file.
9. Now type

   ```
   adb shell
   cd system
   chmod 644 build.prop
   ```
10. And finally, go back to recovery using navigation key and click reboot then click system.

Now, you have enabled multiuser without root.

**NOTE:** Do everything at your own risk. I will not be responsible for any damage to your device.

I posted this because this worked for my Android one.

Comment: `fastboot boot twrp.img` -- does Android one comes with unlocked bootloader or did you unlock your device sometime ago?

Comment: After step 4 `fastboot.exe boot twrp.img` i get the message `< waiting for any device >` without further advanced.

Answer (score -3):

Some models don't support that feature and your phone is one of them.

Comment: The link some phones have this feature disabled, which can still be enabled if you root them - which is not the same as they don't support it at all.