# Multi-user option not available after modifying build.prop in Lollipop

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, multi-user

I edited the build.prop file in /system/ as per
[Multi-user option not avilable in Android one after Lollipop update](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/105539/multi-user-option-not-avilable-in-android-one-after-lollipop-update/123732#123732?newreg=67d4e6dfd580457cb8457e26d612c663)
namely, adding two lines of code to the end of the file:

> fw.show_multiuserui=1
>
> fw.max_users=5

I have rebooted and nothing seems to have changed (i.e., there is no user icon in the swipe-down screen)

I checked and the lines of code are indeed in the build.prop file.
I'm running 5.1.1 on a Lenovo Yoga TAB 3

Any ideas..? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does `adb shell pm get-max-users` give after making changes in build.prop and rebooting the device? Do you see an option named Users under Settings app?

Comment: Have you created a new user and enabled a lock screen? I'm guessing without those you won't see any place to change user until you do.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue and searched for "users" while in the Settings app and it took me to a usable dialog box just as if I had got there from the icon. I added a user and it all worked.  So you just have to search from the magnifying glass in the Settings screen then click on the user you wish to switch to.

Comment: I did a search for users and it came up blank, I'm afraid. As far as I can see, there is no "users" field anywhere in my settings.